# Propel ORM with Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, propel

We are using Zend Framework2, with Propel 1.X as ORM layer and database being Oracle. I did some research on the web, and most of the posts are pointing me to Propel with MySQL db. Could any one please help me with sample connection url that can be used with in propel build config for connecting to oracle.

I have the db url listed in the form of <schemaName>@<HostName>:<PortNo>/<SID>, with username and password as separate params in properties file of propel, but this is not getting me through

Should there be any usage of OCI in this context?

Appreciate any inputs on the method of connecting to Oracle through Propel..

Comment: Yes, it's certainly possible. To work out the connection string I found the connection class and printed out the strings it appeared to need. You'll have to fiddle for a while, but it will work fine. (Mine was on 1.3, so that would have been OCI - yours may be different as it's PDO).

Comment: Thank you for the response.. I shall work out the string and will update the post again..